# Shortcode content is not showing. Only the [shortcode-tag] is showing

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode

I am creating a small plugin where I am creating a few shortcodes. I am using Classic Editor plugin.

Here is my code in Plugin.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Simple Data Visualizer
 * Description: Reads data from CSV and displays data in required format
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: Subrata
 */

function evd_dreambig_shortcode() {
    return 'Hello! Can you dream big?';
}

function register_evd_shortcodes() {
    add_shortcode( 'dream-big', 'evd_dreambig_shortcode' );
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_evd_shortcodes' );
```

But when I put the shortcode in Post content as `[dream-big]`, it is only rendering the tag, i.e. [dream-big] on post page rather than showing its content: *Hello! Can you dream big?*

I also took a different approach:

```
function evd_dreambig_shortcode() {
    return '<h1>Hello! Can you dream big?</h1>';
}

add_shortcode( 'dream-big', 'evd_dreambig_shortcode' );
```

But this does not work either.

I am using a custom theme. I also tried by adding `add_filter( 'the_content', 'do_shortcode');` in functions.php. Still no luck!

`plugin.php` is the only file in my plugin directory.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your exact code works perfectly for me. Is the plugin definitely active? Where are you placing the shortcode? In the visual editor? Does your theme template use the `the_content()` function?

Comment: Would you please mind explaining a bit more?

Comment: Have you activated the plugin in Plugins > Installed Plugins? And where in WordPress are you typing the shortcode? I don't know what else you want me to explain.

Comment: Oh yes! Of course I activated the plugin. And I am writing the shortcode in the editor (classic editor. not using block editor). The shortcode content is only coming after adding `apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );` in single post page. Don;t don't why I am needing this.

Comment: Your template should be using `the_content()`, not `$post` or `$post->post_content`. Make sure you read the documentation on theme development: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-tags/

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the params defaults , like this:

```
evd_dreambig_shortcode($attr = [], $content = null){
    return $content
}
```